# How to get notificaion when Azure restart my web application by itself

Tags: azure, web-applications

I found that Azure sometimes restart my web application by itself for some reason.
For instance today I can see:
Reasons for your web app restart
Around 3/14/2019 6:41:32 AM (UTC), On Instance RD0003FFDF328F, Your application was recycled as the Azure scale unit was undergoing an upgrade. There are periodic updates made by Microsoft to the underlying Azure platform to improve overall reliability, performance, and security of the platform infrastructure where your application is running on. Most of these updates are performed without any impact upon your web app. To reduce the impact of such events on your application, consider deploying your application to multiple regions and use Azure Traffic Manager to distribute the load across regions.

And this has impact on my business, is there any ways how to get any notifications from Azure before update (for instance 1 min before, to store operational data) and/or after update happened (to restore data). Before is more important.

Answer (score 0):

Service Health provides you with a customizable dashboard which tracks the health of your Azure services in the regions where you use them. In this dashboard, you can track active events like ongoing service issues, upcoming planned maintenance, or relevant health advisories. When events become inactive, they get placed in your health history for up to 90 days. Finally, you can use the Service Health dashboard to create and manage service health alerts which proactively notify you when service issues are affecting you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-activity-log-service-notifications?toc=%2fazure%2fservice-health%2ftoc.json